# Taking screenshot of screen(programmatically)

Tags: android, screenshot

I would like to take a screenshot of an Android device programmatically.

I know this question has been asked many times.I am aware of two ways to do it.

1. Using screenshot library(But I am getting black screen all the time).
2. getting data from frame buffer with rooting from `\dev\graphics\fb0`(But it is always 0 byte and I do not know exact location where current screenshot of device is stored). My preferred requirement is getting better frame rate.My code is

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(this, ScreenshotService.class);
      bindService (intent,  new ServiceConnection() {

       @Override
       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
       {

       }
       @Override
       public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
         try {
               asl = IScreenshotProvider.Stub.asInterface(service);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
               Log.e("errrorrrrrrrrrrrrr","errrorrrrrrrrrrr", ex);
         }
       }
   }, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   Button b1=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.widget33);
   b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View view) 
       {
           try {
               asl.takeScreenshot();
           } catch (RemoteException ex) {
               Log.e("nnnnerrrrrrrrrrrrrr","errrrrrrrrrrrrr",ex);
           }
       }
   });
   }'
   ```

Comment: Android does not have a built in screenshot library. What library are you talking about?

Comment: Path separator on Linux is `/` not \.

Comment: Are you talking about taking the screenshot programmatically, or simply using another app, or from Eclipse, or..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [taking screenshot of device screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117870/taking-screenshot-of-device-screen)

Comment: taking the screenshot programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use screenshot, we get the screen images. Are you running it as said, also this could be a device thing, so I suggest you try using the same on other device.

Also some time the problem could be while writing the file back to sd. So Please provide with the full code that you tried.

Answer (score -1):

Dont post one question more than one time.

You can get the drawing cache of your view using the following code:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: I do not want screen shot of only my app but anything that is showing on device screen

Comment: There is no drawing cache for SurfaceView or TextureView