# taking screenshot of device screen

Tags: android, screenshot

I know this question has been asked many times.I am aware of two ways to do it.(1)Using screenshot library(But I am getting black screen all the time).(2)getting data from frame buffer with rooting||\dev\graphics\fb0||(But it is always 0 byte and I do not know exact location where current screenshot of device is stored).My preferred requirement is getting better frame rate.Any help will be very helpful as I have spent a lot of time in this.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. You can use the edit feature to add more info to your original question

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521128/taking-device-screenshot-while-application-is-close/14521173#14521173

Comment: Nimish I have tried all versions of that library but I m getting black screen with demo application.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the drawing cache of your view using the following code:

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$ adb shell screencap -p /mnt/sdcard/sc.png
$ adb pull /mnt/sdcard/sc.png
```

Comment: where should I use these lines?

Comment: from the command line (shell)

Comment: screencap:not found error on android 2.1 device